# Security with nginx

Tags: nginx, ldap, php-fpm, debian-stretch

**Intro**

Okay, I have quite the complicated issue (at least for me) on my soon to be new production network. I am looking for advice from more experienced users with linux, especially advice on secure ways to setup the netwerk I am about the describe. I am still a newbie with all of this and yet I am now responsible for setting up this new network.

Currently I am running around 150+ websites on a setup with one loadbalancer, three webservers and a dataserver in apache. All fine for now, however I am trying to setup a new network with nginx in the new debian because of the huge increase in performance.

I've read lots and lots of information about nginx and apache, run dozens of tests to compare performance in both situations and came to the conclusion that nginx under high pressure (we run almost only WordPress sites) handles requests a lot faster then apache mainly because of the static files (sometimes more then 100 in one page, which the browser can cash obviously but still).

**Current setup**

- Debian 9
- nginx 1.10.3
- php-fpm (7.0)
- ldap 3

I have all the data from websites mounted in a /websites directory on each webserver. The configuration files for nginx and fpm are also located in a configuration directory there. Each website (I'll use example.com) has its own user (authenticated through ldap) and is in the group websites (also in ldap). So each user has his home directory in the /websites folder with permissions 700 owner example.com and group websites. This is done so each website runs in his own isolated "island".

This means that for each website configuration I have an php fpm configuration which uses a different socket for each user. Meaning, it can only execute php files in its own website directory, right?. For PHP this works fine and I rather not change this configuration.

**Issue**

Here comes the issue, nginx is faster because it serves static files directly in comparison to apache which (how we configured it previously) with the mpm-itk module creates separate processes for each user which then serve static files or PHP.

Nginx does this differently, by using php fpm with different sockets for each user I achieve (at least with php) the same as the mpm-itk module does for apache. However nginx can not do this and tries to serve the static files all as the user nginx is run as (www-data as default). So output is generated by PHP (works fine) but nginx does not have permissions to show the static files.

I've been trying to look for a solution for more then a day now and came to a few different conclusions.

**Run as root**

My colleague said running nginx as root will tackle the issue, surely it will but that does not seem secure to me. Might as well remove the entire "each website has it own user" policy if I am at it.

**Add www-data to the websites group**

If I could add a unix user (www-data in this case) to an ldap group (which apparently I can't) I could give the group (websites) read permissions (instead of the current 700) so it can read static files everywhere. Only problem is, websites can read files from each other as well which I am trying to avoid. So this does not seem like a proper solution either.

**SELinux**

I read some documentation and introductions about SELinux and to me this seems like a to complicated way to fix this issue. I never worked with it and running this on a production network like this does not seem like a good idea since I have no idea what I am doing with this.

**Conclusion**

So, from where I am now what path would a more experienced user take? Do more research in SELinux? AppArmor? Or is there another simpler way to get the same security apaches mpm_itk offers.

This is the last issue I have and I am not looking for all the configuration files to set this up and the exact commands I need to execute thats all done.

I hope someone with more experience can give me some advice or point me in the right direction. It is much appreciated anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELinux is worth the time investment IMHO, It's actually not as complex as it appears when you just want to nail down rights to folders.

But let me throw a curveball... If it's mainly Wordpress, I would go with Litespeed Webserver with the Wordpress Cache plugin. You get blazing fast Wordpress through caching at the webserver level:

https://www.litespeedtech.com/products/cache-plugins/wordpress-acceleration

And Litespeed has an easy to implement chroot feature built-in which will take care of your security concerns:

https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:config:chroot

> “chroot” is a feature on Unix like system which can change the root directory of a process. A changed root process and its children process cannot access any file beyond the new root directory. It is like putting a process in a jail with physical file access boundries and the reason why this mechanism is often referred to as “chroot jail”.

Of course, chrooting is also possible with Nginx:

https://gir.me.uk/posts/nginx-php-fpm-with-chroot.html

The Admin GUI of Litespeed just makes it very simple, possibly matching your experience level better than doing everything from the CLI.

Chroot aside, you also have the SuEXEC option:

https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:config:suexec-mode

> SuEXEC is a feature that allow LiteSpeed Web Server run CGI/FastCGI/LSAPI/PHP/Ruby or any external web applications under a UID (user id) other then the UID of the web server process.

This adds further to solving your main worries of running Nginx as root.

I currently use both Nginx and Litespeed for production Wordpress sites. For high-traffic situations as you describe, I would recommend Litespeed with the dedicated plugin any day. Plus you get all the other benefits of rapid file serving that separates both Nginx and Litespeed from Apache.

Comment: I never heard about the litespeed webserver and I am surely going to set it up in a vagrant box to do some performance testing. I've already started with setting up SELinux on one of the webservers, I created a policy for the nginx deamon which now runs in the domain nginx_t but I am still not sure how to set the file permissions. In theory I understand how it works and what I want to achieve, now "only" the implementation. Do you have experience with SELinux by any chance? It'l be nice to have someone around to ask questions from time to time. Thanks for your comment, I will already mark it.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer, and it sounds like you are making great progress. If you ask any SELinux specific questions here, you are bound to get plenty of very helpful answers.